# Azure Active Directory - assign a group to an app programmatically

Tags: azure-active-directory

From Azure portal, I am able to assign a group to an enterprise application.  I can also run powershell script under global admin cred as in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

Is there a way to assign groups to an application programmatically using app id, app secret from an Azure function app? this function is triggered by cosmos db.  When I add/remove groups to/from the cosmos db database, the function app is triggered to add/remove groups to/from an application.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Wouldn't you create a powershell script to do that programmatically?  It seems like the answer to your question is in your question.

Comment: I want to run from a function app, is that possible?  Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to clarify exactly what you mean.  For example, is a "function app" something specific to Azure or are you talking about doing this programmatically from a function in an application you create (in which case you need to put information about the programming language and any frameworks you are using)?  Add that information to your original question so more people can try to answer.

Comment: I added more details to my question. Thanks

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Graph API Create appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to assign a group to an app.

The C# code sample is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example).

Remember to put the app role id into the request body. It is missing in the document. And you should specific the `principalType` as "Group".

Maybe [this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/2#issuecomment-527267234) will be helpful.

Comment: I am able to add a group to an app from a console app. Thanks a lot Allen.

Comment: @KevinPham np:)